# Problem with handling multiple legends in subplots when you use plt.twinx()

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot, legend-properties

I'm struggling to pass the list of my subplots with different scales on sides using `plt.twinx()` in each subplot to show all labels in a single legend box, but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_label'

I have tried the following:

```py
import matplotlib
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
#matplotlib: 3.2.2

#Generate data
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date   = [1,2,3],
    Male   = [10,20,30],
    Female = [20,30,10],
    Others = [700,500,200]
               ))
print(df)

#      Date  Male  Female     Others
#0     1     10       20       700
#1     2     20       30       500
#2     3     30       10       200

# Create pandas stacked line plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Userx = 'foo'
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1 , figsize=(20,10))



plt.subplot(211)
linechart1 = plt.plot(df['Date'],        df['Male'],     color='orange',  marker=".", markersize=5, label=f"Leg1 for {Userx}" ) #, marker="o"
scatterchart2 = plt.scatter(df['Date'],  df['Female'],   color='#9b5777', marker='d', s=70 ,        label=f"Leg2 for {Userx}" )
plt.legend( loc='lower right', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Scale1', fontsize=15)

plt.twinx()
linechart3, = plt.plot(df['Date'],     df['Others'],   color='black', marker=".", markersize=5, label=f"Leg3 for {Userx}" ) #, marker="o"
#lns123 = [linechart1,scatterchart2,linechart3]
#plt.legend(handles=lns123, loc='best', fontsize=15)
plt.legend( loc='best', fontsize=15)

plt.ylabel('Scale2', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp [24hrs]', fontsize=15, color='darkred')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
#lns123 = [linechart1,scatterchart2,linechart3]
#plt.legend(handles=lns123, loc='best', fontsize=15)
#plt.legend(handles=[linechart1[0],scatterchart2[0],linechart3[0]], loc='best', fontsize=15)

plt.subplot(212)
barchart1 = plt.bar(df['Date'],     df['Male'],     color='green',  label=f"Leg1 for {Userx}"     , width=1, hatch='o' ) #, marker="o"
barchart2 = plt.bar(df['Date'],     df['Female'],   color='blue',   label=f"Leg2 for {Userx}"     , width=0.9, hatch='O') #, marker="o"
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.ylabel('Scale1', fontsize=15)

plt.twinx()
barchart3 = plt.bar(df['Date'],     df['Others'],   color='orange',   label=f"Leg3 for {Userx}", width=0.9 , hatch='/', alpha=0.1 ) #, marker="o"

plt.ylabel('Scale2', fontsize=15)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.xlabel('Timestamp [24hrs]', fontsize=15, color='darkred')


bar123 = [barchart1,barchart2,barchart3]
plt.legend(handles=bar123, loc='best', fontsize=15)

#plt.show(block=True)
plt.show()
```

I have tried the following solutions unsuccessfully:

- [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435665/matplotlib-shows-no-legend)
- [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72615525/10452700)
- [using `,`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197471/10452700)
- [How do I make a single legend for many subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834452/how-do-i-make-a-single-legend-for-many-subplots/46921590#46921590) This is not my answer or I couldn't figure it out how I can handle the labels with `plt.twinx()` since it gathered all legends of subplots to a single legend box, while I want to include/integrate into individual legends for each subplot as I marked in the photo.

currently, I just use/duplicate `plt.legend( loc='lower right', fontsize=15)` in `subplot(211)`:

```
plt.subplot(211)
chart1 = ...
chart2 = ...
#here
plt.twinx()
chart3, = ...
#here

plt.subplot(212)
barchart1 = ...
barchart2 = ...

plt.twinx()
barchart3, = ...

bar123 = [barchart1,barchart2,barchart3]
plt.legend(handles=bar123, loc='best', fontsize=15)
```

and get the below output:
[image: img]
The interesting is I don't have this problem for bar plots `plt.bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), based on I could figure out to solve the problem using `get_legend_handles_labels()` to "*keep track of lines and labels*" [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129461/10452700) & [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344146/10452700).

```py
# Create pandas stacked line plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Userx = 'foo'
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1 , figsize=(20,10))
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20,10))

#plt.subplot(111)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(df['Date'],     df['Male'],     color='orange',  marker=".", markersize=5, label=f"Leg1 for {Userx}" ) #, marker="o"
ax1.scatter(df['Date'],  df['Female'],   color='#9b5777', marker='d', s=70 ,        label=f"Leg2 for {Userx}" )
#ax1.ylabel('Scale1', fontsize=15)
ax1.set_ylabel("Scale1", fontsize=15)
ax1.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

ax11 = ax1.twinx()
ax11.plot(df['Date'],     df['Others'],   color='black', marker=".", markersize=5, label=f"Leg3 for {Userx}" ) #, marker="o"
#ax1.ylabel('Scale2', fontsize=15)
ax11.set_ylabel("Scale2", fontsize=15)
ax11.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
ax1.legend( loc='best', fontsize=15)
ax1.set_xlabel('Timestamp [24hrs]', fontsize=15)


#plt.subplot(212)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.bar(df['Date'],     df['Male'],     color='green',  label=f"Leg1 for {Userx}", width=1   , hatch='o' ) #, marker="o"
ax2.bar(df['Date'],     df['Female'],   color='blue',   label=f"Leg2 for {Userx}", width=0.9 , hatch='O' ) #, marker="o"
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
#ax2.ylabel('Scale2', fontsize=15)
ax2.set_ylabel("Scale2", fontsize=15)

ax22 = ax2.twinx()
ax22.bar(df['Date'],     df['Others'],   color='orange',   label=f"Leg3 for {Userx}", width=0.9 , hatch='/', alpha=0.1 ) #, marker="o"

#ax2.ylabel('Scale1', fontsize=15)
ax22.set_ylabel("Scale1", fontsize=15)
ax22.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
#ax2.xlabel('Timestamp [24hrs]', fontsize=15, color='darkred')
ax2.set_xlabel('Timestamp [24hrs]', fontsize=15, color='darkred')
ax2.legend( loc='best', fontsize=15)

# ask matplotlib for the plotted objects and their labels
lines1, labels1   = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines11, labels11 = ax11.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(lines1 + lines11, labels1 + labels11, loc='best', fontsize=15)

lines2, labels2   = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines22, labels22 = ax22.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(lines2 + lines22, labels2 + labels22, loc='best', fontsize=15)

#plt.show(block=True)
plt.show()
```

It seems there is no easy way to solve the problem when you use *2D Lineplot* `plt.subplot(111)` with `plt.twinx()` together, but it works for *bar chatrs*! So it needs to use `ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)` and `ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)` structure to solve the problem.

[image: img]